# AJAX Post to Spring MVC Controller - Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, spring-mvc, http-post

Below are the two snippets to post form data to Spring Controller.

1.

```
$("#formData").submit(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();
            var jqxhr = $.post("submitdata", $("#formData").serialize(), function(data){ 
                console.log(data); 
            }) 
            .success(function() { 
                // Success
            }) 
            .error(function() {  
                // Error 
            }); 
            jqxhr.complete(function(){ 
                //Ajax Process complete... 
            }); 
        });
```

2.

```
$("#formData").submit(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault();
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "submitdata",
                type: "post",
                data: $("#formData").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

**No. 1** posts successfully and displays the response whereas **No. 2** returns **404**.

The URL automatically takes up the context path. Which I can verify from Inspect Element -> Network, and the write URL is fired.

What is the problem can anyone assits? My objective of this problem is to send file along with data to the server.

Comment: It looks fine.  Can you point us at a url where we can see it in action?  It's difficult to tell what's wrong from the above.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong the parameter `contentType`. Just leave it with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The problem is in your form definition. To send a file to the server, just use the first one and put this attribute to the `<form>` tag:

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` (see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp))

Example:

```
<form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    $.post("submitdata", $("#formData").serialize(), function(data){ 
        console.log(data); 
    });
</script>
```